# How do I submit a file using luacurl

Tags: lua, libcurl

I wanted to upload the file to the server using the LuacURL library, but the submission was unsuccessful

```
local curl = require("luacurl")
local result = {}
local c = curl.new()
c:setopt(curl.OPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0)
c:setopt(curl.OPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)
c:setopt(curl.OPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data', 'Referer:https://www.toolnb.com/')
c:setopt(curl.OPT_URL, 'https://api.toolnb.com/Tools/Api/tpzh.html')
c:setopt(curl.OPT_WRITEDATA, result)
c:setopt(curl.OPT_POSTFIELDS, 'r=60&suffix=jpg&file=@/text.png')
c:setopt(curl.OPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function(tab, buffer)
    table.insert(tab, buffer)
    return #buffer
end)
c:perform()
print(table.concat(result))
```

Comment: 1) What exactly was the result? 2) Have you tried the same curl submission from the commad line?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you share with us the output/error?